# How to create products with API Woocomerce batch

Tags: woocommerce-rest-api

I need create products in Woocomerce with data from SQL

```
const { query } = require('express');
var sql= require('....');
var options = {};

options.host = '127.0.0.1';
options.port = 3050;

options.database = 'C:.....;
options.user = 'xxx';
options.password = 'xxxx';


Firebird.attach(options, function(err, db) {

  if (err)
      throw err;

  // db = DATABASE
  db.query('SELECT sku,cant from facturacion', function(err, result) {
  // console.log(result);
```

I get aobject of  array with the query around 80 results, this works fine, who can import this query to Woocomerce for create massively products ,i think wiht a for

```
nst WooCommerceRestApi = require("@woocommerce/woocommerce-rest-api").default;
// import WooCommerceRestApi from "@woocommerce/woocommerce-rest-api"; // Supports ESM

const WooCommerce = new WooCommerceRestApi({
  url: 'xxxx/',
  consumerKey: 'xxx ',
  consumerSecret: xxx',
  version: 'wc/v3'

const data = {

  name: "Premium Quality",
  type: "simple",
  regular_price: "21.99",
  description: "ggg.",
  short_description: "Pxxx.",
  categories: [
    {
      id: 9
    },
    {
      id: 14
    }
  ],
  images: [
    {
      
  ]
};
```

Connection successful